# -Apache- files from "website" not UTF8

Tags: apache, utf-8

ok, lets start from scratch. I just realized this is apache and not phpmyadmin, my bad.

Anyway, I needed some sort of file storage accessible through the web. I deleted the index.html to list the other files in /var/www. Now if I open the json file (UTF8 w/o BOM) in the browser, the special charakters like ä,ü,ö are not correctly displayed (normal chars are). If I download the file, all is correct on my system. 
So the file itself is fine, but the stream from apache to the web is not in UTF8, or something like that. And that I would like to change.

I need this for an android app, where I parse the content of the json file with volley lib. But there it also gets the special charakters wrong.

hope this is more usefull than befor. my apologies for that.

Comment: I'm... confused. You installed Phpmyadmin, you deleted its index.html, you put some .json file there, you click on it, and its characters are garbage? This has absolutely zero to do with phpmyadmin then or MySQL or any settings in my.cnf.

Comment: irrelavant informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that is wrong is that your browser doesn't know it should interpret the UTF-8 encoded JSON file as UTF-8. Instead it falls back to its default Latin-1 interpretation, in which certain characters will screw up, because it's using the wrong encoding to interpret the file.

That is all. The file will appear fine if it is interpreted using the correct encoding, UTF-8 in this case.
Use the View → Encoding menu of your browser to force it to UTF-8 and see it work.

Why doesn't the browser use UTF-8? Because there's no HTTP `Content-Type` header telling it to do so. Why is there no appropriate HTTP header set? Because you didn't tell your web server that it should set this header for .json files. How do you tell Apache to do so? By adding [this line](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addcharset) in an .htaccess file:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .json
```

Comment: ok, sounds logical. at first it didn't work (even after some restarts), but after some renaming of the json files it finally did. thank you.